# PHP File Upload finfo MIME type not detecting correctly?

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

I am checking file MIME types of uploaded files and forcing extensions as so:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);

if ($mime == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
    $extension = ".docx";
} else if ($mime == 'application/msword') {
    $extension = ".doc";
}
```

Regardless of whether the file I upload is .docx or .doc, the statement always evaluates to .doc. Why is docx not being detected? Am I using the wrong mime type?

Same is true for excel files (xlsx, xls)..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/428980 ?

Comment: I am using the MIME type specified there but it doesn't seem to evaluate the if else as true still..

Comment: And what does your `$mime` show?

Comment: I've got this same issue. I've echoed out the mimetype as detected by finfo_file and get `application/octet-stream; charset=binary`, yet mimetype (the perl command) returns `text/csv` successfully.